# using titanium studio, search my 10 closest results, based my search key?

Tags: google-maps, titanium

I am developing android using Titanium studio, my query is I have a Search field, there user can say  Hospital, or Police Station etc.., I have show a list of 10 closest results. I searched for this but I couldn't find any suggestions. will any one suggest me, how to do this?

Comment: [link]https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?key=AIzaSyB-8l0SKg4pCpMG82fxLeZALyk_XaqgZNk&location=13.060416,80.249634&radius=50000&sensor=false[/link] I find this like but what is process? I am new to Titanium any Ideas

Comment: Please check the link http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/141298/how-to-get-nearby-places-in-titanium